# Can Black Panther’s suit repair itself (without having to be worn)?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther

I’m doing a science project, and I’m trying to find a creative example of a non-living thing that can repair itself. I was wondering if anyone knew that if Black Panther’s suit, by itself, can repair/heal itself.

Say you took a sword and cut down the middle of the suit while it's on a stand, would it magically sew back up? Or does T’Challa have to be wearing it?

Comment: I'm reminded of the necrons from 40k. Not sure if that would count. Think zombie space robots

Comment: I don’t think the Black Panther suit is even supposed to heal itself while being worn, is it?

Comment: Some car tires repair themselves! They're filled mostly with air, but along with that air there is some liquid rubber (or something similar). If a nail pokes through the tire, and then is pulled back out, the liquid starts to leak through the hole. Then, it hardens into rubber, plugging up the hole!

Comment: A science project?...

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a non-living thing that can repair itself, look no further than the T-1000!

Made of "mimetic polyalloy" (liquid metal), it can heal bullet holes and explosions within its body.

Spoilered due to disturbing content (super old CGI)

> [image: Creepy Eye Missing]

With *Black Panther*, I don't know that we saw any examples of the suit healing on its own.  Shu'ri mentioned it stores kinetic energy and releases it at once but it's not clear what vibranium properties are or how the suit would behave on its own.

Good luck with your science project!

Comment: That's not CGI, it's a model.

Answer (score 1):

A sword make of anything weaker than vibranium would not cut Black Panther's suit. Even bullets merely create kinetic force for the suit to store and redirect. As the whole thing seems to be nanotech, stored in the necklace, it looks like it should repair itself. However, I don't believe it does.

Actually, Iron Man's latest suit might be a better example for you to use. It does seem to have a mind of its own, though I expect it has more to do with the AI tech built in.

Good luck!